# Parse string in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

```
String response="making year:2011-01-01 id:1011";
```

We want to parse this string like below:

```
t1=making year:2011-01-01;
t2=id:1011;
```

How can I do this in j2me?

Answer (score 2):

```
int index = response.indexOf("id:");
if (index != -1)
{
    String t1 = response.substring(0,index);
    String t2 = response.substring(index);
}
```